# How to be appreciated for working alone and delivering results over "being a team-player"? Please see the description for more details

Tags: management, work-environment, colleagues, career-development, job-change

I have been working in IT as an employee for about 5 years. 
I have had many bad experiences working in teams. I like working alone. I am good at recognizing patterns, doing investigative and analysis work and diving deep into my work alone without distractions. I am INTP-T personality.

I found the work environment in all the companies I have worked so far to be the exact opposite of the type of environment I thrive in. 
What I found in the companies where I worked so far is the following:
Open floor-plans, constant noise, constant chatter, constant discussions around me, Group work, peer-programming, peer-work, group thinking/ group-brainstorming. Interaction with others was more than 80% of the time while solitary work was less than 20 % of the time.

Polder model style of working where you need to reach an agreement and align with every team member on everything (not just with the manager). Team members discussing and debating over stuff ad nauseam. Even when they seem to have reached a consensus on something they revisit and debate over the same stuff again some weeks later.
Lengthy and ineffective group meetings where you are required to actively participate. 
Constant interactions among teammates and between teammates and manager. The need to be available most of the time to them when they walk to your desk and talk otherwise you are “not a team player” in the manager’s view. Same goes with requirement for constant face time with the manager and with the rest of the team.
Employees being forbidden to work remotely or from home on recurring basis. 
Freelancers being treated like employees, being put in an on-site team and forbidden to work remotely or from home.
Team members cherry-picking tasks and fighting over who gets the interesting work first. 
Very frequently asked to give verbal progress reports (every single day and sometimes even multiple times a day). 
Micromanaging.
Team members gossiping to the manager about other team members. Toxic office politics, backstabbing, fights for favoritism, nepotism.
Team members brownnosing the managers and trying to influence the decisions of the managers.
Very frequent change of managers and reorganizations. Very frequent change of direction that has been enforced by others.

I find all of these very demotivating, frustrating, distracting and can’t concentrate on getting my work done. At the same time working remotely and working from home for extended periods of time was forbidden by company policy established after I joined. All of the other companies I worked for had similar written or unwritten rules. Working a day or two from home was allowed but not more than that and not every week!
On multiple occasions when I isolated myself in empty meeting rooms for prolonged periods of time to get some work done in peace and quiet, I was reprimanded by my managers for not interacting enough with the other team members and for not being a “team player”. The rest of the team members had also complained to the manager that I have been working too much on my own, isolating myself, not consulting/reaching consensus with them on everything, not involving them in the work that I do, being too quiet/ not talkative enough to team members, looking disinterested in group meetings with team members and being too pushy with my ideas and with what I need from other team members to get my work done. It seemed like being a “team player” is more important than getting the work done.
For many years, I have been pretending that this is fine with me and I have been pushing myself to be more extroverted, a “team player”, interacting with the other team members, doing team group-brainstorming, peer-programming, mob programming …you name it. The more I pretended to be what I am not the more dissatisfied, irritated, sad and angry I felt in my life. This is not fine with me anymore and I want to change the type of work I do. 
My ideal work would be a work where:

- I can work around 80% of the time alone and about 20% of the time interacting with customers, end-users and other people (not the other way around)
- I can’t speak if most teams are like this or not but if most teams in companies around the world are like this then I prefer to work alone and not in a team.
- I can focus on delivering results and not socializing.
- I can work remotely and not have to show face or give progress reports every single day.
- I can be my own boss (freelance), define my own rate and charge per hour or per value delivered instead of receiving a fixed salary as an employee.
- I can make use of my ability to recognize patterns and dive deeply into investigative and analysis work.
- I can analyze what the customer wants (business requirements), implement them on my own, deliver them, get paid for the work done and have a happy customer amazed with the work that I have done for them and who will recommend me to future clients.
- I receive a personal credit for the work that I deliver and not having to deal with “it was team effort” and “There is no I or me in team”.
- I can outsource (parts of) my work. I can hire people to do work for me. I understand this is not possible as an employee but it should be possible as freelancer, right?
- I can use my ambition for continuous self-improvement, learning new technologies and business aspects, offering services, developing products and making money with that.
  What type of work fits best for my personality? What type of work fits my criteria and what I am looking for? Preferably in IT.

Comment: hi and welcome. this is a lot of text, please try to edit to make it shorter, and maybe add summary section of 1-2 sentences on top. Otherwise this is a very hard question to read and answer

Comment: Hasn't this same question been posted about six times?

Answer (score 1):

It seems really evident that you are frustrated in your current job, and with your past jobs these last 5 years.

You should definitely consider changing jobs to one that is more like the things you mentioned in your bullet points... in fact, I think you answered yourself in a way here:

> I can be my own boss (**freelance**), define my own rate and charge per hour or per value delivered instead of receiving a fixed salary as an employee.

Freelancing seems to be a great option for you, as you have greater control of your time and can do that from the place you want and can concentrate properly.

Naturally, any job involves human interaction at some point, but this option seems to involve an amount more of your liking.

If you are keen on finding patterns and doing analysis, perhaps you can provide freelance consulting or do freelance AI/machine learning.

Answer (score 1):

Realize that by working as a freelancer you can often give yourself more opportunities, but also you take more risk. Ultimately if you are as efficient at work as you say, you should do well. But realize that some of the people you currently work with are doing things that you will be doing by yourself once you are on your own. Things such as deciding on a business strategy. This is a different skillset than software development. Are you going to offer a service or a product? How will you get paid and by whom? Subscription model or one off payments? Are you going to run ads or do other work on social media? Are you prepared to also do system administrator work in addition to development, testing and support? If you take on these tasks you may find that there are ways to get it all done, or maybe outsource some of the work. My advice is simply, don't end up being a freelancer working for the same type of people in large corporations, if you don't like them. They will waste your time. There's plenty of space to compete and get ahead if you are hardworking and focused. A good strategy is to always create new revenue streams that cost you time once, and pay you disproportionately to the time you spent to make them. You'll barely ever need to talk to anyone you don't want to. We live in the age of the internet, where socializing is optional.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of articles have been written about introverts in the workplace.  These articles support much of what you are saying and will both help you feel supported and understood, and also could be useful to provide to your boss so that he/she could read an article and better understand that your request is not frivolous or combative - it's simply the way you are wired and the company can help you reach your best contribution by leaning in to that, versus fighting it.

Absent more understanding about introverts in the workplace, and company policy changes that support what you are asking for, your best bet is to try to find a company that has supportive policies, and more importantly, HR team(s) that understand WHY it's important for an introvert to be supported differently than an extrovert.